# Can't connect to host by hostname

Tags: networking, dns, ping, hosts

I have a problem which can be described by these four lines

```
$ host example.com
example.com has address 10.10.10.10
$ ping example.com
ping: unknown host example.com
```

As I see, hostname resolves fine, but the "ping" command seems to ignore it.
And google searches don't give me anything because this is too specific and I'm not totally sure, how to describe it right. Thanks.

Comment: Is this a local address? As in, is 10.10.10.10 the actual address, or is it just an example?

Comment: Yes, actually the hostname is more like host-1.smth.exmp.local

Comment: And the problem exists only on my laptop. Though I just now thought that it could be avahi daemon.

Comment: Yes, that was avahi screwing up my game. I changed domain-name to .alocal and everything works okay.

Comment: Hi Oleg. Please post answers as answers, not as comments. Comments are for requesting clarification or providing additional information relevant to the post, not to post answers.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was caused by avahi daemon.
I simply changed domain-name setting in /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf to .alocal and uncommented it, and it works now.